# Linux for very old hardware

Tags: linux, hardware

I have a friend who wants to learn unix-like CLI (linux or anything, doesn't care) for some web admin tasks (installing apache and so on)

He only has very old hardware to spare:

- AMD P6 II 300MHz
- 64MB RAM
- HD is more recent: 60GB

I tried the latest Debian & Ubuntu server- to no avail, or I would not have slept all night because of the sheer noise of the computer fan- but I digress...

Do you know any modern linux distrib that supports such an old hardware? Or should I use a very old distrib? (Debian Potato comes to mind)

Or is the hardware definitely too old?

**UPDATE:**

The problem I have with both Ubuntu and Debian is that the installer stalls at 74% (languages, locales). The requested language is Swiss French with a Swiss keyboard (QWERTZ). I don't know if it is relevant...

Also note that (although it will change later, of course) the box did not have any network connection. It may look strange for a would-be server, but it's only for learning at home.

Comment: I started running Linux on 386 computers with 4M of RAM. It is not too old.

Comment: Debian Lenny should run on such hardware easily. Maybe you should describe what your problems are with your install. I've got it running on a machine with similar specs.

Comment: @sybreon: thanks for your comment, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Incidentally you should be able to pick up some dirt cheap second hand RAM. Which would boost what is currently the weakest element of the system.

Comment: You say he has spare hardware. Does that imply he has proper hardware, on which he could run linux virtualized?

Comment: That's a solution worth investigating, yes. Thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: if the installer is hanging and you are using the gui installer switch to the text install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenBSD](http://openbsd.org/) will run fine on that spec.

It was the first sans-GUI operating system that I sank my teeth into many years ago.

Indeed I still ran some of those same machines, at much lower specs than you give, until recently. When I got tired of the clutter, noise and power consumption.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Damn Small Linux wiki](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/index.php/Minimum_Hardware_Requirements), the minimum requirement for Damn Small Linux with X-Windows is 64 Mb. Also, according to this [Pupply Linux Forum](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=32197), you can run Puppy Linux on a machine with 64Mb of RAM.

Comment: And another for DSL.  Simply amazing to get that functionality out of what, 50MB?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to you to install Debian by netinst and setup only what you need (apache, etc).
[Debian NetInst](http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/)

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to learn the Linux/UNIX CLI, does he have a relatively recent PC/Laptop that can run VirtualBox and just install Linux/BSD in a VM?

Comment: +1 It's clearly a better solution than installing Linux on an old harware...

Answer (score 1):

On that hardware, I'd really be going for NetBSD, FreeBSD, or OpenBSD.  Linux is a bit heavy on 64MB of RAM of late without going to uLibc and other stripped/non-standard/embedded solutions.  Debian netinstall or Slackware would work also.  Unfortunately, they don't hold a candle to the BSD documentation (and if he wants to learn the CLI, the FreeBSD/NetBSD/OpenBSD handbooks are priceless).

Answer (score 0):

I have Centos 5.3 (no GUI) on a 400MHz PIII with 512MB of RAM running Hylafax, Nagios, MRTG and Apache as a proxy server. As that isn't much better than what your friend has, Centos may be worth a try, especially if you leave off the gui. I've tried to find the minimum hardware requirements for Centos but can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

i started with freebsd and til this day, the mail server at my old job (5 yrs ago) is still running it. Now I manage a RH network and they have pros and cons to both.

Answer (score -1):

http://linuxfreedom.com/ above link has so many distro you try from them.